# Xcode Mach-O Linker ID error

Tags: c

I am new to xcode an I am trying to learn C Language using Xcode. When I try to run it I get error apple mach- o linker and link command failed with exit code 1. I dont understand other answers on stack overflow about removing pods or library paths. Please Help and tell me each and every step to fix this error.
{Edit}
Sorry for the very little information. Here is the code and the error

[`The Code which was Simple`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM15Y.png)

[Click here for The error which is disturbing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8txR2.png)

```
    Ld /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Products/Debug/Education normal x86_64
    cd /Users/pratikkadam/Documents/GitHub/Education
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -L/Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Education.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Education_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift_static/macosx -Xlinker -force_load_swift_libs -lc++ -framework Foundation -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Education.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Education_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Products/Debug/Education

duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Example.o
    /Users/pratikkadam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Education-dhazvkwqsporefgyqgfaxhlzhscj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Education.build/Debug/Education.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please show your code as well as the verbatim error message. Read this [ask], and this: [mcve].

Comment: Before it printed "linker command failed with exit code 1" there were some other lines, likely including words like "Undefined symbols" and "symbol(s) not found".  What did those lines say?

Comment: You should post the code that you're running so that we can help you

Comment: I have added clarification guys, thank you for helping, Ask other things if needed but I really need to get this working

Answer (score 0):

XCode standard template for command line project in C language contains `main.c` which contains example implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You haven't shown us your project file structure but I assume you didn't remove `main.c` from your project. Your screenshot indicates you created `Example.c` also containing `main()` function definition. In `C` language all functions are on the same flat global level (there no are namespaces & classes) hence the `linker` (final stage of crafting an executable) complains about duplicated `_main` symbol. To solve this problem you should either:

1. Move your test code in main function from `Example.c` to the `main.c` one. And get rid of `Example.c` whatsoever.
2. Rename your function in `Example.c` to **something else** than `main()` and call it inside `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` in `main.c`.

Comment: Thank you very much, This worked. Just answer me, How can I type other programs in the same folder or project without this error occuring. Sorry I am new to this and Thank you very much.

Comment: @Hazardkadam251999 to write code broken into multiple files you should get familiar with the concept of `headers` aka `.h` files in `C` language and your function names must be unique. This goes beyond your original question though.

Comment: yes I am learning that now  and thank you very much for helping